# getClass() of generic class

Tags: java, generics

The problem is that I need to get something like `T.class`, because `veryImportantMethod` (from below example) have Class parameter.

```
public abstract class Something<T> {

    public abstract Class<T> getGenericClass();

}



public class Example extends Something<Example> {
    @Override
    public Class<Example> getGenericClass() {
        return Example.class;
    }
}

public static abstract class BaseDao<T extends Something<T>> extends Amazing {

        T type;

        public T doSomething() {
            this.veryImportantMethod(type.getGenericClass()); 
        }

}

public static class Son extends BaseDao<Example> {
}
```

Actually I'm getting

> ...read of unwritten field... NP_UNWRITTEN_FIELD

How can I go through this?

Comment: What are you asking for? Do you mean to obtain Example.class if your BaseDao instance was initialized like so: ````BaseDao<Example> bd = new BaseDao<Example>();```?

Comment: It seem that you should be getting a NullPointerException but you saying that you get a "NP_UNWRITTEN_FIELD"? Is this actually Java or perhaps Java called by or wrapped by something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure whether this is what you are after but...

First, Example.getGenericClass as defined is totally useless, you would obtain the same answer but calling getClass on the Example typed variable,

```
Example example = new Example();
example.getClass() == Example.class; // always true.
```

Thus If you can guaranteed that `type` will always have a non-null value then you can simply call `type.getClass()` on it.

If `type` might be null then you are kind of out of luck unless you keep record of the class by keeping a separate reference to it. I suspect that `type` is just there to get `Example.class`. In that case is best just
to point to the Class object directly. This reference must be initialized by the constructor and typically it only make sense to make it final since it should not change during the live of the containing object.

```
public static abstract class BaseDao<T extends Something<T>> extends Amazing {

        private final Class<T> clazz;

        public BaseDao(final Class<T> clazz) {
           this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public void doSomething() {
            this.veryImportantMethod(clazz); 
        }
}
...
class ExampleDao extends BaseDao<Example> {
      public ExampleDao() {
         super(Example.class);
      }
}
...
```